# Copy the plots in the NetLogo interface tab

Tags: netlogo

Is there a way to copy plots in NetLogo? I need a relatively large number of plots in the interface tab that have similar code. Creating and adjusting these plots will take time. Is it possible to copy the plots in the interface tab?

Is there a way to copy plots in NetLogo?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not from within the graphical interface, but you can copy plots and pens by opening your model's `nlogo` file in a normal text editor.  [Here are the docs for the format](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/File-%28.nlogo%29-and-Widget-Format), and [here is the section on plot widgets in particular](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/File-%28.nlogo%29-and-Widget-Format#plots).  [Here is an example plot as defined in the Wolf Sheep Predation model](https://github.com/NetLogo/models/blob/master/Sample%20Models/Biology/Wolf%20Sheep%20Predation.nlogo#L320-L339).

You can just copy/paste an existing plot widget in this way, or even the `PENS`, each is on their own line.  I recommend being very careful if you do this - making sure you maintain blank spaces between widgets, the escape slashes `\"` for double-quotes in code, and the exact format of the `PLOT` sections.  I'd take regular back-ups of your file and test your changes frequently as you work in case an edit goes wrong.